# UITextView text color when Editable attribute is disabled

Tags: swift3, uitextview

I migrated an app to Swift 3. I've managed all the changes but I'm struggling with this particular problem. I have some `UITextView` in a `UITable` with are populated with some email address.

In my old Swift 2 version, these views where *not editable*, with the *link data detection* enabled. However, after the migration, with the "not editable" version the text inside the text views is displayed in white color. If if re-activeate the *"Editable"* option, the view content turns again to black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the `dataDetectorType` that you are using? If you are using `link`, you can either change the `tintColor`, or you can use `linkTextAttributes` to manipulate the style to your liking

Comment: Does work! I was trying with `textColor` before. Did something changed with Swift 3? I was not setting the `tintColor` before. Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to be of help. I haven't dealt a lot with textViews in swift 2 so I wouldn't know.